# Changing the name of resource routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have a "CleaningLogEntry", "SalesLogEntry", "ServiceLogEntry" and as so on.

I understand that I can namespace the routes and have them nested. That's good. But I want them to just say log within that namespace. Is it possible

such as

```
resources :facilities do
  resources :cleaning_log_entries
end
```

gives

```
facilities/20/cleaning_log_entries
```

But I want

```
facilities/20/logs
```

This is just the same concept repeated, in case it wasn't clear with some brainstorming

```
resources :client do
  resources :sales_log_entries
end

#From
client/20/sales_log_entries
#To
client/20/logs

resources :services do
  resources :services_log_entries
end
#From
services/20/services_log_entries
#To
service/20/logs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops!

Figured it out. Missed this on Rails Guides:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-named-helpers

You need to add the ":as => 'desired_name'" option for:

```
resources :facilities do
  resources :cleaning_log_entries, :as => 'logs'
end
```